# Switching usb role from host to gadget not working on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb

I'm running Linux on a custom board based on i.MX6 processor. The device tree of a USB port is configured as otg and both roles are working gadget (`g_ether` or `g_serial`) and host (plugging mass storage device). After the boot up the USB is configured as gadget, in this case, I can load `g_ether` and communicate with my laptop without issues. After that, I switch the role to host, and like before it works just fine. I can connect a "mass storage" to the board and the system recognizes it. Finally, when I switch the role again back to gadget, I no longer can make `g_ether` or `g_serial` work. There is no error message on `dmesg`.

**Device tree**

```
&usbotg1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    dr_mode = "otg";
    status = "okay";
};
```

**Linux**

```
root@xxxx:~# uname -a
Linux xxxx 5.4.24-2.0.0+g8115d570b280 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 21 14:56:23 UTC 2021 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**Hardware**

```
1. The board has a mini USB-B female connector
2. The ID pin is connected to ground
3. The +5V is not used (not connected)
```

**Step-by-step commands to reproduce the issue**

```
### 1. After boot the default role is gadget
root@xxxx:~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/ci_hdrc.0/role                                                                                                             
gadget

### 2. Plug laptop and confirm that g_ether is working
root@xxxx:~# ifconfig usb0                                                                                                                                 
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
        inet 192.168.7.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        inet6 fe80::64ba:c3ff:fef0:cfba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 66:ba:c3:f0:cf:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 62  bytes 6802 (6.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 45  bytes 3754 (3.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@xxxx:~# ping -c 2 -w 3 192.168.7.3                                                                                                                            
PING 192.168.7.3 (192.168.7.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.7.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.161 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.023 ms

--- 192.168.7.3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 1.023/1.092/1.161 ms

### 3. Unplug laptop, switch USB role to host and plug mass storage device
root@xxxx:~# echo host > /sys/kernel/debug/ci_hdrc.0/role
root@xxxx:~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/ci_hdrc.0/role
host

root@xxxx:~# dmesg
...
[ 1387.750491] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
[ 1387.802654] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=a4a5, bcdDevice= 2.21
[ 1387.802711] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1387.802745] usb 2-1: Product: USB download gadget
[ 1387.802777] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: FSL
[ 1387.815591] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1387.837391] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 0525 pid a4a5: 10000
[ 1387.838126] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 1389.031295] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
[ 1389.271363] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
[ 1389.511572] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
[ 1389.751624] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc

# sda is present
root@xxxx:~# lsblk 
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    1  7.3G  0 disk 
`-sda1         8:1    1  7.3G  0 part 
mmcblk1      179:0    0  7.3G  0 disk 
`-mmcblk1p1  179:1    0  7.3G  0 part /sysroot
mmcblk1boot0 179:8    0    4M  1 disk 
mmcblk1boot1 179:16   0    4M  1 disk 

### 4. Unplug mass store device, switch USB role to gadget
root@xxxx:~# echo gadget > /sys/kernel/debug/ci_hdrc.0/role                                                                                                        
root@xxxx:~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/ci_hdrc.0/role                                                                                                               
gadget

### 5. Interface is present and g_ether is loaded but can't ping laptop anymore
root@xxxx:~# ifconfig usb0                                                                                                                                     
usb0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
        inet 192.168.7.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        ether 2e:40:4e:6a:3b:8c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@xxxx:~# lsmod | grep g_ether
g_ether                16384  0

root@xxxx:~# ping -c 2 -w 3 192.168.7.3 
PING 192.168.7.3 (192.168.7.3): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.7.3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

If after the last step (5.), I switch to host again it still works fine but gadget won't work anymore. In other words, gadget only works after a fresh boot and host works every time. I've tried different sequences before switching to gadget. For example, unloading `g_ether` first and then switching the role. I also tried `g_serial` to confirm that the issue is not related to the network interface. As I mentioned before there is no error on `dmesg` and right now I don't know how else to debug this issue.

Any ideas of what is happening or how to debug it?

Answer (score 2):

Using the same processor, the IP block is [chipidea](https://github.com/nxp-imx/linux-imx/blob/imx_4.9.11_1.0.0_ga/Documentation/usb/chipidea.txt) and make sure that the Device Tree setting do not have the properties `hnp-disable` and `srp-disable` present.  Use the following example (taken from the Linux documentation).

```
&usbotg {
    vbus-supply = <&reg_usb_otg_vbus>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usbotg_var>;
    ...
    otg-rev = <0x0200>;
    adp-disable;
    status = "okay";
};
```

Once the gadgets are configured, change between Host and Gadget.

Change to Host:

```bash
echo "host" > /sys/kernel/debug/ci_hdrc.0/role
echo "" > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC
```

Change to Gadget:

```bash
echo "gadget" > /sys/kernel/debug/ci_hdrc.0/role
ls /sys/class/udc > /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC
```